# How to imitate IDENTITY behavior with another column?

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql, ddl, dml

I created a table with a column that represents the row's insertion date:

```
create table foo
(
    id int not null primary key identity,
    bar varchar(50),
    insertion_date datetime default current_timestamp
);
```

I use the following statement to insert a new row:

```
insert into test (foo) values ('placeholder');
```

What I want to accomplish is get the behavior of `id` column in `insertion_date` column, so it don't have to be specified in `insert` statement, something like that:

```
insert into test values('placeholder');
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: So what is the error you are getting? what seems to be the problem?

Comment: That's how SQL works.  If you have multiple columns and only want to input a value for a single column you have to specify which column.  You can't just not use the correct syntax because you don't want to.

Comment: *"I don't want to specify columns on insert"* That there is your problem. It's not a matter of " not wanting" to, it's a matter of you **need** to. Not wanting to do something doesn't permit you to write incorrect syntax. I "don't want" to write `DECLARE` before I define my variables or use the keyword `BY` in my `GROUP BY` or `ORDER BY` clauses, but if i don't I get an error. The same principle applies here.

Comment: Probably I don't specified my needings correctly, but it's a fact that I don't want to change the syntax.

Comment: *"I don't want to change the syntax"* You don't have a choice. In fact, the reason you specify the column names in the `INSERT` clause in the first place is so that when you add a column later, you don't break things (unless of course the course the column isn't `NULL`able and has no `DEFAULT` value).

Comment: Perhaps `insert dbo.test default values;`? This will only work if every column has a default value or is nullable. It is still not clear what you are trying to accomplish, but you can't avoid the syntax rules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge one cannot get *exactly* what you are asking for, but one can insert against a view.

```
CREATE VIEW fooView AS 
SELECT id, bar
FROM dbo.foo;
GO
INSERT dbo.fooView VALUES ('baz');
GO
```

The downside is that two different names would be needed for insert and any use that requires `insertion_date`.

*Personally I would not approve a pull request (code review) that did the above to avoid specifying columns on insert.*

Comment: Wow, it was exactly what I needed. In fact, I tried without using ```id``` in ```select``` statement and get the same behavior (I think for ```indentity``` property)`.